# Is it necessary to write your calculations?

Tags: endgame, calculation

I have heard many times that while you're doing endgame studies,you should write your calculations,like candidate moves,variations.Is it really necessary?Can't i just check each variation one at a time in my head without having to write it down.

Comment: We all learn differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  You could do it if it helps you.
I would not waste the time writing it down when I could be using it to learn something else.